# NSFetchedResultsController created, but sections is nil

Tags: ios, core-data, rubymotion

I ran into what I believe is a defect, but I'm not sure if it's in my code, or in RubyMotion, or in iOS...

"tag" model:

```
class Tag < CDQManagedObject
  def sectionIdentifier
    puts "Called"
    name ? name[0] : " "
  end

  def keyPathsForValuesAffectingSectionIdentifier
    NSSet.setWithObject("name")
  end
end
```

Part of my controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
self.query = Tag.sort_by(:name)
self.tags_results = NSFetchedResultsController.alloc.initWithFetchRequest(self.query.fetch_request, managedObjectContext: cdq.contexts.current, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier", cacheName: nil)
self.tags_results.delegate = self
puts tags_results.sections.inspect
```

The problem is, tags_results.sections is nil.  I have something wrong here, but I am not sure where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm...

I've never used rubymotion before so not 100% certain.

However, if that is all the code you are using then I think I see the problem.

The `NSFetchedResultsController` is created and you give it the request, sectionIdentifier, etc...

However, you are not telling the controller to actually run the fetch.

In `Objective-C` I would do...

```
[fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

This tells the controller to go and actually get the results.

Only then is the sections property filled.

The `sections` property is an array of the actual fetched objects so without fetching them it will always be nil.

**EDIT**

Yes...

From the documentation... http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/NSFetchedResultsController.html#performFetch%3A-instance_method

You need to run...

```
self.tags_results.performFetch(nil)
// or whatever the syntax is
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was the problem exactly.